# Run a script after knockout has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a front-end script that alerts when a link is clicked.  The problem is, the link that my script looks for is loaded on the page via a knockout template, and I can't get my script to run after that happens.

I am not able to execute this within knockout, unfortunately, it must be done within my front-end CMS.  Not ideal, I know.

Is there any way to work around knockout and ensure my script runs AFTER the knockout template has finished loading? I got it to work with a timeout, but that's not ideal.  I've also tried docready, onload, etc, and no dice.

My script is very simple, I'm wondering if there is something specific to knockout that I can wrap it in...

```
  $('.myLink').on('click', function(event) {
  var foo  = $(this).text();
  alert(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attach the event handler to an ancestor that *does* exist on the page on page load and create a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.myLink', function (event) {
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the HTML for the link that is needed to attach the event, is encapsulated in a KO `template`, one could specify an `afterRender` parameter

Comment: @Tyblitz  Could you give me a rough example of what that might look like?  If I know the template name, or, some html in the template? `<!-- ko template: {name: 'tmpl-example'} -->



<div class="myExample">
<div class="myExampleChild" data-bind="text:name">SomethingHere</div>
</div>`

Comment: @user3390251: There's some documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove) as well